# How to get BuildNumber in .proj (MSBuild) using TFS server

Tags: msbuild

We use TFS 2010 with VS 2010 for PHP web projects. Actually we do not have any .proj or .sln file, so i have made my own to make builds, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>
    <ItemGroup>
        <ZipFiles Include="**\*.*"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Zip" >
        <Zip Files="@(ZipFiles)" ZipFileName="$(OutDir)myzip.zip" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="Zip">
        <Message Text="My Build Complete - $(BuildNumber) - $(TeamProject) - $(BuildProperties)" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="AfterBuild">
        <MakeDir Directories="Testing" />
        <Message Text="My AfterBuild- $(BuildNumber) "></Message>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

I have configured build numbers in build definition in VS as "$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)" , and drop folder on network path is created correctly.

The problem is that $(BuildNumber) or $(TeamProject) or $(BuildProperties) are empty. Also it seems that "My Afterbuild" is never executed.

Why are my variables empty and how to get build number from build definition as specified?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To run `AfterBuild` targets:

```xml
<DefaultTargets="AfterBuild" />

<Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="Zip">

<Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="Build">
```

For me is not clear why `Zip` target should be executed before the `Build` target?

**EDIT:**

You have to update template file `defaultTemplate.XAML` by adding manually BuildNumber to the MSBuild command line so command Line would be like:

```xml
<mtbwa:MSBuild CommandLineArguments="[String.Format(&quot;
        /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true 
        /p:BuildNumber={1} {0}&quot;, 
        MSBuildArguments, 
        BuildDetail.BuildNumber)]" />
```

See the original article regarding this trick: [TFS2010 – Where is $(BuildNumber)?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2011/01/26/tfs2010-where-is-buildnumber.aspx)

Comment: Yes, sorry about mistake with DefaultTargets. Anyway first zip, then Build which does only Message. Also on lot of forums the $(BuildNumber) is standard same as $(OutDir), but it does not work in my case, maybe i need something else ? How can i get buildnumber from build definition ? , Also AfterBuild should be executed again after Build is complete, no need in my case, someone told that then will BuildNumber variable be available , but it is not, you can ignore then AfterBuild. Also i can not pass any arguments to msbuil, since it is Build agent server on TFS 2010 server.

Comment: Are you have access to the process template file defaultTemplate.XAML  ?

Comment: yes i have, i can made a copy and modify it. tell me what i need to do

Comment: @Hrvoje Kusulja: see edit part of my answer, you need to add manually /p:BuildNumber={1} parameter and pass it as BuildDetail.BuildNumber

Comment: Ok, thank you I see. I have modified in this way, however i get: MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch. Switch: -  For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help". I have TFS 2010 on 2008 R2 server. Did look for type but no details. :/

Comment: OK this is because of $(BuildDefinitionName) as part of string, so i have modified it to "$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)" and now it works, thank you very much !!!

Comment: That BuildNumber is confusing - I assumed it should contain just the number of each build in that day. But BuildNumber contains entire BuildName, and the actual daily build number is $(Rev). Oh, Microsoft, sometimes your logic is weird...