# How to pass TFS variable to a MSBuild task of the project

Tags: tfs, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have a solution which is built on TFS server. This solution includes several projects which have custom MSBuild tasks. Theses tasks actually create some zip archives.

I need to extract somehow the $(Rev) macros from the TFS build and pass it to the tasks. I tried to use MSBuildArguments in the process tab of the build definition and it works when I set a simple string value like:

/p:Version="5"

but it doesn't work with the macros:

/p:Version="$(Rev:r)"

[image]

do you have any ideas?

Edit: I actually needed BuildDetail.BuildNumber.

Comment: May I ask what makes you think those are macros?

Comment: Hm, I just thought it is called macros. Check the build number format - it is built with these macros. Am I wrong? I'm a newbie in TFS.

Comment: Yes, they're not general. The build number format thing is specific to the build number.

Comment: Actually I need just to add some unique number of a current build to the archive names. Could you suggest anything?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can slightly change your build process template to achieve that.
By default the section that relates to MSBuild looks like this:
[image]
This could be expanded into something like this:
[image]
If you now enter in "MSBuild Arguments" of your build definition (similar to your picture) something like `/p:Version=RePlAcE`, you should get what you need.
 In another build definition where you don't need this, simply leave the entry empty. This approach is an alternative to the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330353/how-to-get-buildnumber-in-proj-msbuild-using-tfs-server), and should be chosen if this version-insertion is not explicitly desired for all build definitions consuming it.

Comment: yes, thank you. I already did exactly the same