# How do I pass MSBuild arguments from the build definition to a MSBuild workflow Activity

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I've defined an MSBuild activity in a TFS Workflow template, but currently I have to hard code the 'property' command line arguments directly into the template.

I'd like to be able to specify the arguments in the build definition, via the advanced setting, 'MSBuild Arguments'

I can see that I may have to build up the command line with string replace/concat, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030328/how-to-pass-tfs-variable-to-a-msbuild-task-of-the-project), but I can't see what I need to put, maybe something like this:

[image: "/P:MyProperty=" + BuildDetail.Properteis("MyProperty")]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the default MsBuild task uses:

> String.Format("/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true {0}", MSBuildArguments)

You can change the `MSBuildArguments` variable in the build process template in multiple steps. For example, I added a Run Architecture Validation property to the process template and then edited the workflow to simply append `/ValidateArchitecture=true` to the `MSBuildArguments` before they're being passed to the MsBuild activity.

```
 <If Condition="[PerformArchitectureValidation]" DisplayName="Configure Architecture Validation MSBuild Arguments">
  <If.Then>
   <Assign>
    <Assign.To>
     <OutArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String">[MSBuildArguments]</OutArgument>
    </Assign.To>
    <Assign.Value>
      <InArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String">[MSBuildArguments + " /p:ValidateArchitecture=true"]</InArgument>
    </Assign.Value>
   </Assign>
  </If.Then>
 </If>
```

The `PerformArchitectureValidation` variable is defined as a Property on the Build Process Template level of type `Boolean`.

---

Update: [Wrote a blogpost that explains this with steps and screenshots](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/07/properly-incorporate-msbuild-arguments.html)

Comment: How is the PerformArchitectureValidation defined & set? Cheers.

Comment: Ok I figured it out, we can add custom arguments to the build template that appear in the build definition, that's the approach that I've gone for, Many thanks.

Comment: @jessehouwing similiarly how can i pass two parameter to `PostBuildScriptArgs` in xaml build definition?

Comment: @nithinchabdran just append them to the variable.

Comment: Just like the example does with `[MsbuildArguments]`